# Get the Path of a .mp3 raw resource from URI

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to send an audio file to Dialogflow from an Android app.

In order to do that I need the Path of the audio file. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/how/detect-intent-audio), it goes like this:

```
val videouri: URI = URI.create("android.resource://$packageName/raw/tts")
val videopath: Path = Paths.get(videouri)
val inputAudio: ByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(videopath)
```

However, on the second line, when obtaining the Path I get the following exception:

```
java.nio.file.filesystemnotfoundexception provider android.resource not installed
```

The audio file is located in res > raw > tts.mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, raw resources are not files on the filesystem of the device.

Second, a `URI` is not a file.

Use `Resources` and `openRawResource()` to get an `InputStream` on the resource. IIRC, there is a `readBytes()` extension function in Kotlin that you can use to read in the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.`
See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources